# CKEditor mentions (autocompletion) having a different text content and mention id?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am trying to add a plugin into CK Editor where I can alter the textContent of the mention to be the value of the attribute label.

```
    function MENTION_ENGINE(
        editor: Parameters<
            // @ts-ignore
            Parameters<typeof ClassicEditor.create>[1]["plugins"][number]
        >[0]
    ) {
        editor.conversion.for("upcast").elementToAttribute({
            view: {
                name: "span",
                classes: "mention",
                attributes: {}
            },
            model: {
                key: "mention",
                value: (viewItem) => {
                    console.log({ viewItem });
                    const mentionAttribute = editor.plugins
                        .get("Mention")
                        .toMentionAttribute(viewItem, {
                            // Add any other properties that you need.
                        });

                    return mentionAttribute;
                }
            },
            converterPriority: "high"
        });

        editor.conversion.for("downcast").attributeToElement({
            model: "mention",
            view: function (modelAttributeValue, { writer }) {
                if (!modelAttributeValue) {
                    return;
                }

                console.log({modelAttributeValue})

                return writer.createAttributeElement(
                    "span",
                    {
                        class: "mention",
                        "data-mention": modelAttributeValue.id,
                        "data-jsonpath": modelAttributeValue.jsonpath,
                        "data-label": modelAttributeValue.label
                    },
                    {
                        priority: 20, // Mention's priority in relation to other attributes
                        id: modelAttributeValue.uid // Unique ID to prevent merging mentions
                    }
                );
            },
            converterPriority: "high"
        });
    }
```

The upcast is model value function is also not running.

Expected the `writer.createAttributeElement` to return a HTML Element where I could just directly modify the textContent and set the label